# How do I parametrise this line integral properly?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

$ F (x,y,z) = ( zy + sinx , zx - 2y , yx-z ) $ is the vector field.

Find the line integral of F which has curve C given as $ x = y = z^2 $ between (0,0,0) and (1,1,1)

I first did this:

Take $ z=t $ so $ z^2= t^2 $ and hence, $ x=y=t $ given parametrisation as

$ r(t) = ( t, t, t^2 ) $ and $ r'(t) = ( 1 , 1 , 2t ) $

But I am not so keen on this because after finding F[ r(t) ] I get a long expression which is then calculated with r'(t) via dot product. I do NOT think this is correct simply because the question is not worth many marks so shouldn't require too much effort.

Is the parametrisation $ r (t) = ( 1 , 1 , t) $ by any chance? Could you kindly explain how to parametrise the curve, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z = t \implies x = y = t^2 \implies F(x,y,z) = F(t^2, t^2, t) = (t^3 + sint, t^3 - 2t^2, t^4 - t)$$
Now 
$$\mathbf r'(t) = (2t, 2t, 1)$$

And the line integral is calculated as usual with the dot product. Unfortunately, I don't know of a more effortless way.

Edit:

Actually, after thinking for a bit, it occurred to me that there is a quicker way in the case of this particular vector field.
Notice that $zy + sinx, zx - 2y, yx - z$ are the partial derivatives w.r.t. $x$, $y$ and $z$ respectively of $G(x,y,z)=xyz - cosx - y^2 - \frac 12 z^2$. The [gradient theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem) therefore applies, and the integral equals $G(1,1,1) - G(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks Nigel, I did the (kinda) opposite.. After obtaining that, then would I need to compute the dot product of that eqn with ( 2z, 2z, 1) and if not, why?

Comment: Yeah fair enough, thanks!

Comment: Sorry - edited again. I found the 'easier way'!

Comment: Thanks for those details. Since we are on topic, how do we find G ( x, y, z)  ? E.g. do we find integral of first component wrt to x to be $ xyz- cos (x) + h( y , z) $ and then work from there?

Comment: Yes, but we have to do that for each of the entries, since we are only hoping (checking to see) that they are partial derivatives of some $G(x,y,z)$. Then we check that the terms in each entry's integral which are functions of multiple variables give the correct results when differentiated w.r.t. the variables contained (crossing them out in all appearances once checked), and if all such terms end up crossed out with no terms producing inconsistent derivatives (e.g. $sinx$ in the $y$ position has no corresponding $ycosx$ in the $x$ position), we have confirmed our scalar field $G$.

Comment: Systematically:  1. Integrate each entry  2. Check across integrated entries that terms which are multivariable functions, when differentiated by each of the variables contained, have the correct results as terms in the original entries. As you do this, cross out the terms which are checked and write the integrated term down as part of a sum.  3. Once all terms are checked and no discrepancies in the derivatives are found, add the single-variable functions to the sum and you have G.

Comment: Alright thanks! I've noticed that when I continue using my initial parametrisation of $ r(t) = (t , t , t^2) $ and substitute the values into $ F [r(t)] $  I get $ (t^3 + sint, t^3 - 2t,0) $ !! Dot product this with $ r'(t) = ( 1, 1, 2t) $ leads to the same answer and seems quicker! Understanding both methods is useful so thanks

Comment: You're welcome! But don't you mean $r(t) = (t^2,t^2,t)$?

Comment: No no, I'm saying if you use the parametrisation I mentioned instead then at one point, the third component of F[r(t)] is 0 which makes it much faster to do in regards to the integration! It also gives the same answer as the parametrisation you mentioned

Comment: Oh, so in other words for the curve $x^2 = y^2 = z$?